# How do I get the information that the user has changed in a table in PyQT with Python and SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I have a table that comes up on my GUI. The user can edit this table from the GUI. how do I get all of the information that has been edited and update it in the database? The user checks the checkbox for each row they want to have updated to the database, so I have a list of all rows that require updating. I want to have a list of tuples, where each tuple is a row of new values that need to be updated, given that the ID field remains unchanged (I also want to know how to make the user unable to edit some fields).

```
def click_btn_mailouts(self):
    self.screen_name = "mailouts"
    self.cur.execute("""SELECT s.StudentID, s.FullName, m.PreviouslyMailed, m.nextMail, m.learnersDate, m.RestrictedDate, m.DefensiveDate FROM
                        StudentProfile s LEFT JOIN Mailouts m ON s.studentID=m.studentID""")
    self.all_data = self.cur.fetchall()

    self.table.setRowCount(len(self.all_data))
    self.tableFields = ["Check","Full name","Previously mailed?","Next mail","learnersDate","Restricted date","Defensive driving date"]
    self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.tableFields))
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.tableFields)
    self.checkbox_list = []
    for i, item in enumerate(self.all_data):
        FullName = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[1]))
        PreviouslyMailed = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[2]))
        LearnersDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[3]))
        RestrictedDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[4]))
        DefensiveDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[5]))
        NextMail = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[6]))
        self.table.setItem(i, 1, FullName)
        self.table.setItem(i, 2, PreviouslyMailed)
        self.table.setItem(i, 3, LearnersDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 4, RestrictedDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 5, DefensiveDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 6, NextMail)
        chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.checkbox_list.append(chkBoxItem)
        self.table.setItem(i, 0, self.checkbox_list[i])

"""here is the format that I have for the edit function"""

def click_btn_edit(self):
    checkedRows = []
    for i, checkbox in enumerate(self.checkbox_list):
        if checkbox.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            checkedRows.append(i)
            """as the list itterates, if the checkbox item is ticked, 
            it passes through the if statement, otherwise it is ignored.
            checkedRows becomes a list of all the indexes in the table where
            an edit needs to be made"""
```

So basically I need to know how to get the changes made in the QTableWidget in the GUI given a list of indexes where changes have been made, and somehow get those changes updated into the database. It would also be helpful to know how to stop the user from editing some of the fields, as that would mess up the database.

Comment: Is it necessary to manipulate the database manually? PyQt offers a great interface called `QtSql` where you can define a database connection `QtSql.QSqlDatabase`. This is then managed by a database model `QtSql.QSqlTableModel` and connected to a `QtGui.QTableView`. In this way, changes in the QTableView are directly reflected in the database without the need to write any database-queries. A good starting point might be this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_database_handling.htm

Comment: I am forced to be self-taught in PyQT, so I didn't know that this even existed. My program is already too dependent on QTableWidget. Is there a way that you can set an edit strategy for QTableWidget, or a way that you can access the data that the user has edited in the table?

Comment: I still think that it's worth using the QtSql interface. Since QTableWidget inherits from QTableView I cannot imagine that you would need to change much in your code except for deleting a lot of unnecessary lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a few different things.

To prevent editing, you can just remove the edit flag for the items you don't want the user to edit

```
FullName.setFlags(FullName.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

It looks like you're storing the original data (i.e. `self.all_data`).  You could just compare the data in the selected table cells with the original data and only update fields that have changed.

You could also connect to the [`itemChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal for the table widget and keep a running list of all the indexes that have changed since the last refresh

```
    ...
    self.changed_items = set()
    self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)

def log_change(self, item):
    self.changed_items.add(item)
```

Alternatively, depending on how much control you want, you can also create a `QItemDelegate` to do all of this.

Comment: When I tried the first suggestion, I got the error: 
AttributeError: 'QTableWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setItemFlags'. I put them at the bottom of the function 'click_btn_mailouts()'

Comment: I removed the 'item' from 'setItemFlags' and it worked, thank you.

Comment: What is the item in the function you provided? If it is QTableWidgetItem I may need an explanation for what that is, because I dont really know how the items work.

Comment: So I now have a list of records that have been edited, but the records are the unedited records. Is there a way I can get the edited records?

Comment: @PaulJackways I'm not sure what you mean.  The edited data should be contained in each of the `QTableWidgetItem`'s text.

Comment: I have the code:

            `FullName.setFlags(FullName.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            NextMail.setFlags(NextMail.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        self.changed_items = set()
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)` ..............................................................................                                          
    `def log_change(self):
        self.changed_items.add(self.item)
        print(self.item)`

and it prints what the records had before they were edited.