# How do you get data from QTableWidget that user has edited (Python with PyQT)

Tags: python, pyqt

I asked a similar question before, but the result didn't work, and I don't know why.
Here was the original code:

```
def click_btn_printouts(self):
    self.cur.execute("""SELECT s.FullName, m.PreviouslyMailed, m.nextMail, m.learnersDate, m.RestrictedDate, m.DefensiveDate FROM
                        StudentProfile s LEFT JOIN Mailouts m ON s.studentID=m.studentID""")
    self.all_data = self.cur.fetchall()
    self.search_results()
    self.table.setRowCount(len(self.all_data))
    self.tableFields = ["Check","Full name","Previously mailed?","Next mail","learnersDate","Restricted date","Defensive driving date"]
    self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.tableFields))
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.tableFields)
    self.checkbox_list = []
    for i, self.item in enumerate(self.all_data):
        FullName = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[0]))
        PreviouslyMailed = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[1]))
        LearnersDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[2]))
        RestrictedDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[3]))
        DefensiveDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[4]))
        NextMail = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[5]))
        self.table.setItem(i, 1, FullName)
        self.table.setItem(i, 2, PreviouslyMailed)
        self.table.setItem(i, 3, LearnersDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 4, RestrictedDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 5, DefensiveDate)
        self.table.setItem(i, 6, NextMail)
        chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.checkbox_list.append(chkBoxItem)
        self.table.setItem(i, 0, self.checkbox_list[i])
```

The suggested code to add was this (indentation accurate) to the end of the function:

```
    self.changed_items = set()
    self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)
```

And add the following function:

```
def log_change(self):
    self.changed_items.add(self.item)
    print(self.item)
```

The expected print was the edited data, but what I get is the data before it was edited.

I can't use QTableView and QtSql unless I can find a way to use it with an SQL query, get every selected record into a list, and stop certain columns from being edited. If anybody knows how to do these, that would be great, I just really have no time to go through all the documentation myself at the moment.

All I want to do is have the user be able to change data from the QTableWidget, and get that changed data as a record.

Basically, my end goal is to have the equivalent of `setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)` for QTableWidget.

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and I just want it sorted out, it is the last thing I need to do to finish this program for a client.

Comment: In the accepted answer in [the other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742199/how-do-i-get-the-information-that-the-user-has-changed-in-a-table-in-pyqt-with-p), it said `def log_change(self, item):` `self.changed_items.add(item)` while here you quote `.add(self.item)` which is of course different.

Comment: It should still be the same. I have converted the item to self.item so that it works with my program.

Comment: The reason you get the old data is because you use `self.item` instead of the solution from the answer in your previous post.

Comment: What I have done is exactly what the other answer said. The `def log_change(self,item)` comes right after the `def click_btn_printouts(self)` inside the MainWindow class.

the printouts function now ends like so:
            `NextMail.setFlags(NextMail.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)  \n
        self.changed_items = set()  \n
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)`

and log change function is this:
    `def log_change(self, item):  \n
        self.changed_items.add(item)  \n
        print(item)`

I now get the error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'QTableWidgetItem'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always difficult to answer without a minimal working example, so I produced one myself and put the suggestion from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742199/how-do-i-get-the-information-that-the-user-has-changed-in-a-table-in-pyqt-with-p) in, modifying it, such that it outputs the changed item's text and its position inside the table.

```
# runs with Python 2.7 and PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(600,200)

        self.all_data = [["John", True, "01234", 24],
                         ["Joe", False, "05671", 13],
                         ["Johnna", True, "07145", 44] ]

        self.mainbox = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainbox.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainbox)

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Update',self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.click_btn_printouts()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.update)

    def click_btn_printouts(self):

        self.table.setRowCount(len(self.all_data))
        self.tableFields = ["Name", "isSomething", "someProperty", "someNumber"]
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(self.tableFields))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.tableFields)
        self.checkbox_list = []
        for i, self.item in enumerate(self.all_data):
            FullName = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[0]))
            FullName.setFlags(FullName.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
            PreviouslyMailed = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[1]))
            LearnersDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[2]))
            RestrictedDate = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.item[3]))

            self.table.setItem(i, 0, FullName)
            self.table.setItem(i, 1, PreviouslyMailed)
            self.table.setItem(i, 2, LearnersDate)
            self.table.setItem(i, 3, RestrictedDate)

        self.changed_items = []
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.log_change)

    def log_change(self, item):
        self.table.blockSignals(True)
        item.setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor("red"))
        self.table.blockSignals(False)
        self.changed_items.append(item)
        print item.text(), item.column(), item.row()

    def update(self):
        print "Updating "
        for item in self.changed_items:
            self.table.blockSignals(True)
            item.setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor("white"))
            self.table.blockSignals(False)
            self.writeToDatabase(item)

    def writeToDatabase(self, item):
        text, col, row = item.text(), item.column(), item.row()
        #write those to database with your own code


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App()
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You may use this example now to refer to any further problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.